# How do I idiomatically check and process custom JWT claims?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, authorization, auth0

I'm using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) for authentication and have users with various roles & permissions. The JWT tokens returned don't have the permissions listed in the `scope` claim - they are part of a `permissions` [claim](https://community.auth0.com/t/permissions-claim-or-scopes/30156). The payload sample looks like this:

```json
{
  "iss":"...",
  "sub":"...",
  "scope":"openid profile email",
  "permissions":[
    "x:create",
    "x:read",
    "x:update",
    "x:delete"
  ]
}
```

I need to ensure the JWT token has the right set of permissions before processing the request. My current solution consists of a custom annotation, `HasPermissions`, which I add to the relevant controller methods:

```java
  @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
  @HasPermissions({"x:delete"})
  public ResponseEntity<Item> delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    service.delete(id);
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
  }
```

The annotation, and corresponding permissions, are then checked in a custom `HandlerInterceptor`:

```java
class PermissionsInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
      HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod) handler;
      HasPermissions perms = method.getMethodAnnotation(HasPermissions.class);
      if (perms != null) {
        String[] permissions = perms.value();
        if (!hasPermissions(token(), permissions)) {
          response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  JwtAuthenticationToken token() {
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    if (context == null) {
      return null;
    }
    Authentication auth = context.getAuthentication();
    if (auth instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken && auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      return (JwtAuthenticationToken) auth;
    }
    return null;
  }

  // other methods ommited.
}
```

The `hasPermissions` method checks if the permissions listed in the annotation are present in the token `permissions` claim.

**Question:**
Is the above a reasonable solution, or is there a more idiomatic/optimal/safer way of verifying and/or handling a custom JWT claim?

Comment: The thing you are trying looks more of ABAC (attribute based access control)
And it has many complete solutions. Check that.
Basically ABAC is generalized way of doing what you are doing.
It provides policy, rules depending on what type of entity, what fields, what action can be performed by User having what role.

Comment: Looking at your implementation, it looks llike you are implementing low level security logic. This kind of logic is already provided by Spring Security. To extract authorities you can do something like this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction